# How to get the url of the document in quick parts?

Tags: url, word, document-template, quick-parts

I have document library in which there is one content type with the document template uploaded. In the footer of the document, I want to show the URL of the document which is opened in word application.

Is there any way to get the URL?  I am not able to see the field in Quick Parts while configuring footer of document template.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single line text site column in that content type to hold URL information.
Create a SPD workflow to populate URL field using update field of current list.
This custom column will be available as Quick part in word.
This could be an alternate approach as URL is not available as quick part field.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make the hyperlink clickable :(